# How can I edit the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file?

Tags: mac, ssh

I tried editing the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file on my Mac to change the **forwardX11** from **no** to **yes**, and this to enable X11 features.

I try to change permission in the file `ssh_config` and in the folder `etc`, I did it, but in vain; still no permission to go inside the file to change something.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) How are you accessing the file? Which editor are you using?

Comment: I use simply TextEdit

Comment: Are you comfortable using vim in the Terminal?

Comment: Can you run `ls -ld /etc /etc/ssh_config /etc/ssh /etc/ssh/ssh_config` and **paste** the result into the question? And add the specific error message you get as well (screenshot).

Comment: Thank you, i find the answer, with this line : 
'sudo nano -w /etc/ssh/ssh_config'
Thanks again.

Comment: *"I try to change permission in the file ssh_config and in the folder etc, I did it, but in vain..."*   You should not change the **permissions** for `/etc` or for `/etc/ssh_config`. You should use `sudo` [as you have shown in your answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343622/149366) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the answer, with this line in Terminal :

```
sudo nano -w /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be editing `~/.ssh/config` anyway. Modern versions of Mac OS will back out any changes you do to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` upon reboot.

Comment: On reboot or OS updates?

Comment: @nohillside Reboot (as of the updates last year to Catalina)

Comment: Strange.Just tested with Big Sur, custom changes in /etc/ssh/ssh_config remained after a reboot. Upgrades tend to undo changes in /etc so it's a good idea to keep changes somewhere else anyway.